# Unable to generate the Tiktok access token for web

Tags: tiktok, tiktoktemplate

Here is my Request Post URL:

https://open-api.tiktok.com/oauth/access_token/?client_key=fgjvjhg&client_secret=ghhjgjhgjkhjk&code=Web&grant_type=authorization_code

Here is the response which I got:

{
"data": {
"captcha": "",
"desc_url": "",
"description": "Authorization code expired",
"error_code": 10007
},
"message": "error"
}

Here is the documentation page which I am following:
https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/login-kit-manage-user-access-tokens

Please help me with that, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing 2 values there:

1. Code (Authorization code from Web/iOS/Android authorization callback)
2. grant_type (should always be set as *authorization_code*)

Example request:

```
https://open-api.tiktok.com/oauth/access_token/?client_key={{key}}&client_secret={{secret}}&code={{client_unqiue_id}}&grant_type=authorization_code
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your code to make sure you're not making duplicate requests. A second request will invalidate the first one and you'll get `Authorization code expired`.